# How do I order a dataframe by a string variable and by a numeric or date variable in descending order?

Tags: r, date, sorting, numeric

I have a dataframe and I want to order it by a character column and by a date or numeric column.

It works when I order both in ascending order:

```
dataframe <- dataframe[order(dataframe$stringvariable, dataframe$numericvariable),]
```

However, I cannot figure out how to order it by the numeric variable in descending order.

When I try the code below, I get error message "Error in -dataframe$numericvariable : invalid argument to unary operator:"

```
dataframe <- dataframe[order(dataframe$stringvariable, -dataframe$numericvariable),]
```

When I try the code below instead, I get error message "argument 2 is not a vector" and "Unknown or uninitialised column: `numericvariable`."

```
dataframe <- dataframe[order(dataframe$stringvariable, rev(dataframe$numericvariable)),]
```

It works when I only order by numericvariable, but I cannot figure out how to do this when I want to order by more than one column.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `order(letters, -(1:26))` works, so it is not just a matter of one field being character and one numeric. What seems more likely is that your `$numericvariable` is really strings of numbers. Please add reproducible sample data.

Comment: and fyi if you want to reverse order a string or factor variable, you can use `xtfrm`: `order(-xtfrm(letters))`